# Karatzas and Shreve Problem 3.2. A generating family for the trace $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(T_1, \dots, T_n)$ with the set $\{N_s = n\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This is part of the solution to problem 3.2 (i) in Karatzas and Shreve. 
Here, $T_1, T_2, \dots$ is a sequence of independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda>0$. $S_0 = 0, S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n T_i$. And $N_t = \max\{n \ge 0: S_n \le t\}$ for $0\le t < \infty$.

I have question about the last sentence of the following excerpt. I know that $\mathscr{H}$ is generated by sets of the form $\{T_1 \le t_1, \dots , T_n \le t_n, N_s = n\}$ since the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(T_1, \dots, T_n)$ are generated by such sets $\{T_1 \le t_1, \dots , T_n \le t_n\}$. However, how is it generated by $\{S_1 \le t_1, \dots, S_{n-1}\le t_{n-1}\}$? 
[image]

Comment: Certainly $\sigma(S_1,...,S_n) = \sigma(T_1, ..., T_n)$. But I don't know how to make the $S_n$ disappear in the generating set, because $T_n$ is independent of $S_1,...,S_{n-1}$ sp doesn't depend upon them, while $N_s = n$ doesn't put enough hold on arbitrary variation of $S_n$, which is permitted in $\sigma(S_1 , ..., S_n)$.